# t4 templates per template TransformOnBuild setting

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-generation, t4

I would like to automatically execute one of the .tt files when my project is built, but not the others. Is it possible to set the TransformOnBuild property on specific .tt files instead of project wide? Or another method to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have decided to add a custom pre build step to generate the .tt files needed:

```
<Exec Command="&quot;%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Common Files\microsoft shared\TextTemplating\10.0\TextTransform.exe&quot; template.tt -out template.cs" />
```

This method also allowed me to easily pass parameters (defined in the project file) to the template with -a; another problem I was facing.

Comment: +1 for the workaround; I totally forgot the TextTemplating. In case you need to distribute the TextTransform.exe (or other components) to support build environment without VS, you might want to look at MonoDevelop; it provides MIT/open-source licensed compatible T4 implementation.

Comment: Yeah this is the only way i got it working as well... Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Answering as another method to accomplish this.

1. You could change your .tt as TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor
   (descibed better here:
   http://www.olegsych.com/2009/09/t4-preprocessed-text-templates/).
2. Create small command line tool that executes the preprocessor on pre-build event.

The first link includes this example, but it describes the use of preprocessed class:
http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/pga/vs10-beta-1-t4-preprocessing-part-2/

Comment: In case someone needs to run more advanced scenarios, the preprocessed template comes into play, however the OPs workaround is much simpler way to achieve the common required functionality.

Comment: This is a good example as to why answers should be self contained, rather than relying on (dead) links.