# How can I auto-compile T4 templates on build in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, t4

In Visual Studio 2012, there was a plugin that auto-compiled all T4 templates in your solution called AutoT4. This plugin is not available for Visual Studio 2013 yet.

Does anyone have a technique in getting T4 templates to compile on build?

I know some have created batch scripts to do this, but I'm looking for a simpler solution. Maybe something in the pre-build events?

Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to easily configure using the TextTrasnform.exe on the pre-build event. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565351/t4-templates-per-template-transformonbuild-setting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AutoT4 has been updated with support for VS 2013/2015, so that should work for you now.